# getting text of unique li

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/43j8f/1/) is the Fiddle. I am making my own custom drop down box (because I want to style it), and I am having trouble getting the unique text of an `<li>`. The reason I want to do this is: in default drop down boxes, it shows the text of what you clicked in the box. To be more specific, I am trying to get text from the `<li>` you *clicked*, and put it in the `<div id='click'>`.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ol').hide();
    $('#click').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('down');
        $('ol').toggle();
        $('.l').click(function () {

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this question still open? If not, please close the question (by choosing a best answer) and upvoting any answers that were helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/43j8f/6/)

In your `$('.l').click()` function

Change:

```
var l = $('.l').html();
```

To:

```
var l = $(this).html();
```

Incidentally, it is not recommended to use class/ID names that are also methods/commands. (Eg. #click)

I also updated the jsFiddle link to demonstrate showing/hiding the dropdown after selection

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: There's no need to add an event listener to elements with class `l` each time you click `#click`

**Demo**: <del>http://jsfiddle.net/43j8f/2/</del> http://jsfiddle.net/43j8f/5/

Use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ol').hide();
    $('#click').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('down');
        $('ol').toggle();
    });
    $('.l').click(function () {
        $('#click').html($(this).html());
    });
});
```

If you use

```
$('.l').click(function () {
    $('#click').html( $('.l').html() );
});
```

the problem is that `$('.l')` contains all elements with class `l`, and `.html()` only gives you the text of the first one, instead of the one that you clicked.

According to http://api.jquery.com/html/,

> In an HTML document, `.html()` can be used to get the contents of
>   any element. If the selector expression matches more than one element,
>   **only the first match** will have its HTML content returned

Instead, when you use event handlers, `this` is the element which fired the handler.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler,

> It is often desirable to reference the element from which the event
>   handler was fired, such as when using a generic handler for a series
>   of similar elements. When attaching a function using
>   `addEventListener()` the value of this is changed—note that the value of
>   `this` is passed to a function from the caller.

Comment: Excellent answer Oriol - +1

Comment: Thanks! [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/SZSMP/) of all my form elements so far.